# How can I use a dark background theme for the cells for Microsoft Excel 365 (online)?

Tags: excel-online, dark-mode

How  can I use a dark background theme for the cells for Microsoft Excel 365 (online)? For Microsoft Excel 365 offline, I use the "Create new style" option. However for Microsoft Excel 365 online, the "Create new cell style" option doesn't seem to be available.

---

**Dark mode for cells in Microsoft Excel 365 offline:**(***For reference only***)

Create new cell style:

[image]

[image]

White font:

[image]

Black background:

[image]

Apply new cell style to all cells:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the information necessary to answer it.  External links and images are helpful but shouldn't supplant relevant details.

Comment: @BlindSpots thanks, the question is "How can I use a dark background theme for the cells for Microsoft Excel 365 (online)?". What information is missing to be able to answer it?

Comment: [What information is missing to be able to answer this question asking how one can use a dark background theme for the cells for MS Excel 365 (online)?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5206/18147)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently still no solutions to use a dark background theme for the cells for Microsoft Excel 365 (online) using the built-in features of Microsoft Excel. One may instead use one's browser dark mode, e.g. Dark Reader on Chrome:

[image]

Note that Chrome's dark mode doesn't work make Microsoft Excel 365 (online)'s dark.